# Two datepickers of ui-bootstrap on a single page each pop-up only once

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I believe that I have followed the advice of others such as the good answer to "How to have at least two datepickers of ui-bootstrap on a single page?" and successfully incorporated two of them on my page.  While I can endlessly edit the text version of each date, I can only have the pop-up calendar for each date occur only once.  Extra clicks on the calendar icons seem to do nothing.

What have I done wrong?  I don't see that this is expected behavior or what option I've left off or accidentally included.

relevant html is:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="startDate" is-open="openedStart" datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close" />
  <button type="button" ng-click="open($event,'openedStart')"></button>
  <input type="text" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="endDate" is-open="openedEnd" datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close" />
  <button type="button" ng-click="open($event,'openedEnd')"></button>
```

relevant js code is:

```
$scope.openedStart = false;

$scope.openedEnd = false;

$scope.format = "dd.MM.yyyy";

$scope.open = function($event,opened) {
  $event.preventDefault();
  $event.stopPropagation();

  $scope[opened] = true;
};
```

Comment: Have you tried  $parent.openedStart  instead of just openedStart?

Comment: @Scott where do recommend that be tried, exactly?

Comment: In the input tag. You have is-open="openedStart".  See if is-open="$parent.openedStart" helps. Also see the answer below. I was wondering exactly what you were trying to do with the $scope[opened] = true as I'm not sure that make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating an object. Something like this:

html:

```
<input type="text" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="startDate" is-open="opened.openedStart" datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close" />
<button type="button" ng-click="open($event,'openedStart')"></button>
<input type="text" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="endDate" is-open="opened.openedEnd" datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close" />
<button type="button" ng-click="open($event,'openedEnd')"></button>
```

Your controller:

```
$scope.opened = {};
$scope.opened.openedStart = false;
$scope.opened.openedEnd = false;

$scope.open = function($event,datepicker) {
  $event.preventDefault();
  $event.stopPropagation();
  $scope.opened[datepicker] = true;
};
```

Comment: Thank you @clagos.  I lost something in the translation first time around from single use to multiple use of the datepicker.  Your answer works great for me.